# Fragment IllegalStatexception on getResources()

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

I have this line inside `SubCategoryFragment`:

```
s.group_name = SubCategoryFragment.this.getResources().getString(R.string.everything_else); // line 315 in stacktrace
```

My understanding was that by adding SubCategoryFragment.this to this would prevent the IllegalStatexception.

This is a `ListFragment`.  This occurs when someone clicks on a list item in this fragment, and goes to another; then hits the back button and returns to `SubCategoryFragment`.  `onActivityCreated()` where this line above ultimately resides.

I don't do anything inside `onDetach()` related to this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:608)
  at ---.---.com.--.SubCategoryFragment.buildSubcategories (SubCategoryFragment.java:315)
  at ---.---.com.---.SubCategoryFragment$2.onResponse (SubCategoryFragment.java:287)
  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run (ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fragment.getResources()` is a convenience call that fetches the `Resources` object from whatever `Activity` your fragment is currently attached to. If your fragment isn't attached to any activity, it will throw `IllegalStateException`.

Calling `SubCategoryFragment.this.getResources()` vs just `getResources()` won't make any difference.

There are two possible solutions to this problem. The first is to move the call to a place where you are guaranteed that your fragment will be attached to some activity. The other is to get a `Resources` object from somewhere other than the fragment (and therefore the fragment's activity). If you have access to some other `Context` object (perhaps by having a `View` you can call `View.getContext()` on), you can call `Context.getResources()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to test this.  I guess I need to find out how to handle a detached fragment in onActivityCreated().  Or prevent that from happening.