# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Report from Google Developer Console

Tags: java, android

So I have my application published in the Play Store and it seems like some of my users are facing crashes. I am trying to reproduce it to get logs, but not able not so stuck with the error log provided by Google.

But I am honestly not able to understand the issue here from the log so need your help!

**Crash Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:614)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:678)
  at com.tinyapps.newsly.providers.priceticker.currencydetails.chartandtable.GraphFragment.lambda$getCMCChart$0$GraphFragment (GraphFragment.java:243)
  at com.tinyapps.newsly.providers.priceticker.currencydetails.chartandtable.GraphFragment$$Lambda$0.onTaskCompleted (Unknown Source:8)
  at com.grizzly.rest.GenericRestCall.afterCall (GenericRestCall.java:1054)
  at com.grizzly.rest.GenericRestCall.onPostExecute (GenericRestCall.java:1030)
  at com.grizzly.rest.GenericRestCall.onPostExecute (GenericRestCall.java:55)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:695)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:712)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6753)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:482)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Code Of this Fragment**

```
public class GraphFragment extends Fragment implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    private int chartFillColor;
    private int chartBorderColor;
    private String cryptoID;
    private int percentageColor;
    private LineChart lineChart;
    private View rootView;
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;
    private IAxisValueFormatter XAxisFormatter;
    public final IAxisValueFormatter monthSlashDayXAxisFormatter = new MonthSlashDayDateFormatter();
    public final TimeDateFormatter dayCommaTimeDateFormatter = new TimeDateFormatter();
    public final MonthSlashYearFormatter monthSlashYearFormatter = new MonthSlashYearFormatter();
    private String currentTimeWindow = "";
    private SingleSelectToggleGroup buttonGroup;
    public static String CURRENT_CHART_URL;
    public final static DecimalFormat rawNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
    private LockableNestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    private int displayWidth;
    private ProgressBar chartProgressBar;
    private String tsymbol;
    private CurrencyFormatterSingleton currencyFormatter;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    NumberFormat chartUSDPriceFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat fullDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static final String SHAREDPREF_SETTINGS = "newsly_settings";
    public static final String CHART_SPINNER_SETTING = "chart_spinner_setting";
    public static final String ARG_SYMBOL = "symbol";
    public static final String ARG_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COIN_OBJECT = "COIN_OBJECT";

    public GraphFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static GraphFragment newInstance(String symbol, String id) {
        GraphFragment fragment = new GraphFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_SYMBOL, symbol);
        args.putString(ARG_ID, id);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setColors(float percentChange) {
        if (percentChange >= 0) {
            chartFillColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.materialLightGreen, null);
            chartBorderColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.darkGreen, null);
            percentageColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.percentPositiveGreen, null);
        }
        else {
            chartFillColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.materialLightRed, null);
            chartBorderColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.darkRed, null);
            percentageColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getActivity().getResources(), R.color.percentNegativeRed, null);
        }
    }

    public void setUpChart() {
        XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(false);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(true);
        lineChart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
        lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        lineChart.setContentDescription("");
        lineChart.setNoDataText(getString(R.string.noChartDataString));
        lineChart.setNoDataTextColor(R.color.darkRed);
        lineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        lineChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
                YAxis yAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
                // Allow scrolling in the right and left margins
                if (me.getX() > yAxis.getLongestLabel().length() * yAxis.getTextSize() &&
                        me.getX() < displayWidth - lineChart.getViewPortHandler().offsetRight()) {
                    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                    nestedScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
                viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                nestedScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {

            }
        });
    }

    public LineDataSet setUpLineDataSet(List<Entry> entries) {
        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Price");
        dataSet.setColor(chartBorderColor);
        dataSet.setFillColor(chartFillColor);
        dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
        dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
        dataSet.setCircleColor(chartBorderColor);
        dataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        dataSet.setDrawValues(true);
        dataSet.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        dataSet.setHighLightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        dataSet.setCircleRadius(1);
        dataSet.setHighlightLineWidth(2);
        dataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false);
        dataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false);
        dataSet.setHighLightColor(chartBorderColor); // color for highlight indicator
        return dataSet;
    }

    public void getCMCChart() {
        final TextView percentChangeText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.percent_change);
        final TextView currPriceText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_price);
        currPriceText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        lineChart.setEnabled(true);
        lineChart.clear();
        chartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CoinMarketCapService.getCMCChartData(getActivity(), cryptoID, cmcChartData -> {
            List<Entry> closePrices = new ArrayList<>();
            if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
                for (List<Float> priceTimeUnit : cmcChartData.getPriceUSD()) {
                    closePrices.add(new Entry(priceTimeUnit.get(0), priceTimeUnit.get(1)));
                }
            } else {
                for (List<Float> priceTimeUnit : cmcChartData.getPriceBTC()) {
                    closePrices.add(new Entry(priceTimeUnit.get(0), priceTimeUnit.get(1)));
                }
            }
            if (closePrices.size() == 0) {
                lineChart.setData(null);
                lineChart.setEnabled(false);
                lineChart.invalidate();
                percentChangeText.setText("");
                currPriceText.setText("");
                lineChart.setNoDataText(getResources().getString(R.string.noChartDataString));
                chartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }
            XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(XAxisFormatter);
           // TextView currentPriceTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_price);
            float currPrice = closePrices.get(closePrices.size() - 1).getY();
            TextView chartDateTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphFragmentDateTextView);
            chartDateTextView.setText(getFormattedFullDate(closePrices.get(closePrices.size() - 1).getX()));
            if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
                currPriceText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.unrounded_usd_chart_price_format), String.valueOf(currPrice)));
            } else {
                currPriceText.setText(currencyFormatter.format(currPrice, "BTC"));
            }
            currPriceText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            float firstPrice = closePrices.get(0).getY();
            // Handle edge case where we dont have data for the interval on the chart. E.g. user selects
            // 3 month window, but we only have data for last month
            for (Entry e: closePrices) {
                if (firstPrice != 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    firstPrice = e.getY();
                }
            }
            float difference = (currPrice - firstPrice);
            float percentChange = (difference / firstPrice) * 100;
            if (percentChange < 0) {
                if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
                    percentChangeText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.negative_variable_pct_change_with_dollars_format), currentTimeWindow, percentChange, Math.abs(difference)));
                } else {
                    percentChangeText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.negative_variable_pct_change_without_dollars_format), currentTimeWindow, percentChange));
                }
            } else {
                if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
                    percentChangeText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.positive_variable_pct_change_with_dollars_format), currentTimeWindow, percentChange, Math.abs(difference)));
                } else {
                    percentChangeText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.positive_variable_pct_change_without_dollars_format), currentTimeWindow, percentChange));
                }
            }
            setColors(percentChange);
            percentChangeText.setTextColor(percentageColor);
            LineDataSet dataSet = setUpLineDataSet(closePrices);
            LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
            lineChart.setData(lineData);
            lineChart.animateX(800);
            chartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }, new afterTaskFailure() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskFailed(Object o, Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Server Error: " + e.getMessage());
                lineChart.setNoDataText(getString(R.string.noChartDataString));
                chartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, true);
    }

    public void setDayChecked(Calendar cal) {
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.clear();
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_WINDOW, cryptoID, startTime, endTime);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.oneDay);
        XAxisFormatter = dayCommaTimeDateFormatter;
    }

    public void setWeekChecked(Calendar cal) {
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.clear();
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_WINDOW, cryptoID, startTime, endTime);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.Week);
        XAxisFormatter = monthSlashDayXAxisFormatter;
    }

    public void setMonthChecked(Calendar cal) {
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.clear();
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_WINDOW, cryptoID, startTime, endTime);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.Month);
        XAxisFormatter = monthSlashDayXAxisFormatter;
    }

    public void setThreeMonthChecked(Calendar cal) {
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.clear();
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_WINDOW, cryptoID, startTime, endTime);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.threeMonth);
        XAxisFormatter = monthSlashDayXAxisFormatter;
    }

    public void setYearChecked(Calendar cal) {
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.clear();
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_WINDOW, cryptoID, startTime, endTime);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.Year);
        XAxisFormatter = monthSlashYearFormatter;
    }

    public void setAllTimeChecked() {
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.AllTime);
        CURRENT_CHART_URL = String.format(COIN_MARKETCAP_CHART_URL_ALL_DATA, cryptoID);
        XAxisFormatter = monthSlashYearFormatter;
    }

    public void setTable(CMCCoin coinObject, View rootVeiw) {
        String usdFormat = getString(R.string.usd_format);
        String negativePctFormat = getString(R.string.negative_pct_format);
        String positivePctFormat = getString(R.string.positive_pct_format);
        int negativeRedColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.percentNegativeRed);
        int positiveGreenColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.percentPositiveGreen);
        TextView nameTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableNameDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getName() == null) {
            nameTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            nameTextView.setText(coinObject.getName());
        }

        TextView priceUSDTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tablePriceUSDDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getPrice_usd() == null) {
            priceUSDTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            priceUSDTextView.setText(String.format(usdFormat, Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getPrice_usd())));
        }

        TextView priceBTCTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tablePriceBTCDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getPrice_btc() == null) {
            priceBTCTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            priceBTCTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.btc_format), coinObject.getPrice_btc()));
        }

        TextView volumeTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableVolUSDDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getVolume_usd_24h() == null) {
            volumeTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            volumeTextView.setText(String.format(usdFormat, Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getVolume_usd_24h())));
        }

        TextView mktCapTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableMktCapDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getMarket_cap_usd() == null) {
            mktCapTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            mktCapTextView.setText(String.format(usdFormat, Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getMarket_cap_usd())));
        }

        TextView availSupplyTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableAvailableSupplyDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getAvailable_supply() == null) {
            availSupplyTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            availSupplyTextView.setText(rawNumberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getAvailable_supply())));
        }

        TextView totalSupplyTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableTotalSupplyDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getTotal_supply() == null) {
            totalSupplyTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            totalSupplyTextView.setText(rawNumberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getTotal_supply())));
        }

        TextView maxSupplyTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableMaxSupplyDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getMax_supply() == null) {
            maxSupplyTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            maxSupplyTextView.setText(rawNumberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getMax_supply())));
        }

        TextView oneHrChangeTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.table1hrChangeDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getPercent_change_1h() == null) {
            oneHrChangeTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getPercent_change_1h());
            if (amount >= 0) {
                oneHrChangeTextView.setText("Change 1h\n" +String.format(positivePctFormat, amount));
                oneHrChangeTextView.setTextColor(positiveGreenColor);
            } else {
                oneHrChangeTextView.setText("Change 1h\n" +String.format(negativePctFormat, amount));
                oneHrChangeTextView.setTextColor(negativeRedColor);
            }
        }

        TextView dayChangeTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.table24hrChangeDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getPercent_change_24h() == null) {
            dayChangeTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getPercent_change_24h());
            if (amount >= 0) {
                dayChangeTextView.setText("Change 24h\n" +String.format(positivePctFormat, amount));
                dayChangeTextView.setTextColor(positiveGreenColor);
            } else {
                dayChangeTextView.setText("Change 24h\n" +String.format(negativePctFormat, amount));
                dayChangeTextView.setTextColor(negativeRedColor);
            }
        }

        TextView weekChangeTextView = rootVeiw.findViewById(R.id.tableWeekChangeDataTextView);
        if (coinObject.getPercent_change_7d() == null) {
            weekChangeTextView.setText("N/A");
        } else {
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(coinObject.getPercent_change_7d());
            if (amount >= 0) {
                weekChangeTextView.setText("Change 7d\n" +String.format(positivePctFormat, amount));
                weekChangeTextView.setTextColor(positiveGreenColor);
            } else {
                weekChangeTextView.setText("Change 7d\n" +String.format(negativePctFormat, amount));
                weekChangeTextView.setTextColor(negativeRedColor);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
        lineChart = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        chartUSDPriceFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        chartUSDPriceFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
        setUpChart();
        currencyFormatter = CurrencyFormatterSingleton.getInstance(getContext());
       // WindowManager mWinMgr = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       // displayWidth = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        chartProgressBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chartProgressSpinner);
        // Button sourceButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sourceButton);
        // sourceButton.setPaintFlags(sourceButton.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(SHAREDPREF_SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Spinner chartCurrencySelector = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chartCurrencySelectSpinnr);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chart_spinner_options));
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        tsymbol = sharedPreferences.getString(CHART_SPINNER_SETTING, "USD");
        chartCurrencySelector.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
            chartCurrencySelector.setSelection(0);
        } else {
            chartCurrencySelector.setSelection(1);
        }
        chartCurrencySelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // ((TextView) chartCurrencySelector.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tsymbol = spinnerArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(CHART_SPINNER_SETTING, tsymbol);
                editor.apply();
                getCMCChart();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        viewPager = (CustomViewPager) container;
        nestedScrollView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphFragmentNestedScrollView);
        buttonGroup = rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart_interval_button_grp);
        cryptoID = getArguments().getString(ARG_ID);
        setDayChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
        buttonGroup.check(R.id.dayButton);
        currentTimeWindow = getString(R.string.oneDay);
        // sourceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //     @Override
        //     public void onClick(View v) {
        //         CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        //         CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        //         customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(BASE_CMC_SOURCE_URL + cryptoID));
        //     }
        // });
        buttonGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
            Calendar.getInstance();
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.dayButton:
                    setDayChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
                case R.id.weekButton:
                    setWeekChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
                case R.id.monthButton:
                    setMonthChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
                case R.id.threeMonthButton:
                    setThreeMonthChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
                case R.id.yearButton:
                    setYearChecked(Calendar.getInstance());
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
                case R.id.allTimeButton:
                    setAllTimeChecked();
                    getCMCChart();
                    break;
            }
        });
        CMCCoin coinObject = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra(GraphFragment.COIN_OBJECT);
        setTable(coinObject, rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    // test commit

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        TextView currentPrice = rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_price);
        currentPrice.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myTextPrimaryColor));
        TextView dateTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.graphFragmentDateTextView);
        if (tsymbol.equals("USD")) {
            currentPrice.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.unrounded_usd_chart_price_format), String.valueOf(e.getY())));
        } else {
            currentPrice.setText(currencyFormatter.format(e.getY(), "BTC"));
        }
        dateTextView.setText(getFormattedFullDate(e.getX()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }

    public String getFormattedFullDate(float unixSeconds) {
        Date date = new Date((long)unixSeconds);
        return fullDateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

Thank you, looking forward to getting some help!

Edit: As per the docs, **IllegalStateException** error is occurred when the code is repeated, at least that's what my understanding is but my code has nothing repeated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment IllegalStatexception on getResources()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723082/fragment-illegalstatexception-on-getresources)

Comment: that `IllegalStateException` most likely is coming from the `Fragment` not being attached to a `Context` (an `Activity`) - when trying to call a convenience method, which assumes that this would be the current state, while it isn't. what's the statement at line `243`??

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for the reply! Line 243: `currPriceText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.unrounded_usd_chart_price_format), String.valueOf(currPrice)));`

Comment: @StevenRõgrê and there's the `getResources()` being called ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be prevented ...

```
public void getCMCChart() {
    if(getActivity() != null) {
       ...
    }
}
```

`getResources()` assumes that the `Fragment` is attached to an instance of `Context` - which results in an `IllegalStateException`, when the method is being called during the illegal state of `!isAttached()`. one could also check with `getContext() != null` or with `isAttached()`.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll try it on and see. Thanks!

Comment: Should I implement     
`@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }`

And then use mContext to get resources? Is that a better option?

Comment: @StevenRõgrê there is definitely no way to provide the `Context` while the state is `!isAttached()`. `super.onAttach(context);` is what provides it to the instance of `Fragment`, automagically - therefore there it makes little sense to override that method.

Comment: okay, thank you so much! I wasn't actually able to reproduce the crash in any of my test devices but have implemented your solution. Hope this fixes it. Thank you again, appreciated it.

Comment: @StevenRõgrê this only prevents the crash... while the fundamental question might be, why `getCMCChart()` is even is being called during that state (which would permit a proper fix). `if(isAttached()) {getCMCChart();} else {Log.d("GraphFragment", "problem");}` would also prevent it, while indicating when it happens.

Comment: That's what even I'm trying to figure out. But as I said, none of the devices I tested with caused any crashes so couldn't get the actual logs from AS and just stuck with the limited ones provided by Google. it's strange actually. Nevertheless, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @StevenRõgrê you could log to `Crashlytics` ... to determine which devices are affected. eg. `Samsung` provides their own emulators, so one does not necessarily have to get such a device.

Comment: Haven't implemented Crashlytics yet since the app is in beta stage. But after this error, I'll just add it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, IllegalStateException is used to indicate that "a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time." However, this doesn't look like a particularly typical use of it.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Illegal State Exception is an Unchecked exception. It indicate that method has been invoked at wrong time.

Example :

```java
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
//
//
t.start();
```

We can not start the Thread again, it will throw IllegalStateException.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't see any repeated code in my Fragment so don't know what must've been wrong here.

Comment: This is not just about repeating code. It also means that you have restarted a thread that you have already started.